# Why do subclasses of android classes not require calling of super-constructor?

Tags: java, android

I've noticed that classes that subclass android classes don't require having a constructor and calling the constructor of the superclass. Why is that? I thought all classes except pojo's needed a constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not overriding the constructor. There's no requirement* saying you need to override the constructor of the superclass.

> I thought all classes except pojo's
>   needed a constructor?

They have a constructor. It's inherited from their parent class. You're just not REIMPLEMENTING the constructor.

*As noted by @Christian, you would need to implement a constructor if the parent class's constructor took arguments. In the case of android classes (most), they don't.

Comment: Ah. I guess that was a fundamental of java that I misunderstood. I thought even if you aren't reimplementing the constructor you still had to call it somehow.

Comment: *There's no requirement saying you need to override the constructor of the superclass.* if the super-constructor has parameters, then yes: it's mandatory to override it.

Comment: Also, you need to call the constructor of your superclass if it sets private final fields.

Comment: Just being picky, but you can't actually override the constructor of a superclass :)  You can only write a constructor for your child class which calls the constructor of a superclass.

Comment: I'll pile on to the previous nit pick: there is no constructor inheritance.  The compiler will politely generate a no-arg constructor that calls the superclass constructor.  If you dump the bytecode you can see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Well... those classes you are talking about have a default constructor (one with no parameters). If they had parameters (like the `View` class), then you MUST override at least one constructor.